# Run With Timeout Function With Capture Output (with proper threading and queue)

Tags: python, concurrency

i am trying optimize a function `run_with_timeout` that basically takes a command (such as `ping google.com`), with a timeout (`10` seconds) and capture as well as display the console output of the process. Under normal circumstances, this works fine, but going through how to properly do concurrency from one of the core developer of Python (https://youtu.be/9zinZmE3Ogk?t=3332), there need to be threading and queue for this. So the `print_manager` function is exclusively for print, and `queue_line` is the worker thread. (Continue below)

**Code:**

```py
def queue_line(data, print_queue):
    for line in iter(data.readline, ''):
        print_queue.put(line)
    data.close()

def print_manager(print_queue):
    while True:
        line = print_queue.get()
        print(line, end='')
        # Inform `print_queue` that the job is done
        print_queue.task_done()

def run_with_timeout_v2(command, timeout):
    # Create the process
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        universal_newlines=True,
        text=True,
        )
    
    process.timed_out = False
    process.output_buffer = ''

    print_queue = Queue()
    print_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_manager, args=(print_queue,))
    print_thread.daemon = True
    print_thread.start()
    del print_thread

    worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=queue_line, args=(process.stdout, print_queue))
    worker_thread.start()

    try:
        print_queue.put('In Try')
        process.wait(timeout=timeout)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        print_queue.put('In Except')
        process.timed_out = True
        process.kill()
    finally:
        print_queue.put('In Finally')
        worker_thread.join()
        print_queue.join()
```

**Expected Output**

```
In Try
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=9.70 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=11.0 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=9.46 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=12.7 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=10.6 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=117 time=10.1 ms

In Except
In Finally
```

This mostly works fine until you try to simulate high workload environment with fuzzing, which amplify some of the race conditions. What's a proper way to correct this?

**Example Fuzz Code:**

```py
def queue_line(data, print_queue):
    for line in iter(data.readline, ''):
        utils.fuzz(is_fuzz=True)
        print_queue.put(line)
        utils.fuzz(is_fuzz=True)
    data.close()


def print_manager(print_queue):
    while True:
        line = print_queue.get()
        utils.fuzz(is_fuzz=True)
        print(line)
        utils.fuzz(is_fuzz=True)
        # Inform `print_queue` that the job is done
        print_queue.task_done()
...
```

**Fuzz Output:**

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

In Try
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=9.65 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=9.53 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=15.4 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=9.97 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=11.5 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=117 time=12.1 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=117 time=10.7 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=117 time=11.3 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=117 time=14.3 ms

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=117 time=10.1 ms

In Except
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=11 ttl=117 time=10.5 ms

In Finally
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=117 time=12.1 ms
```

Comment: After killing the process, main code should `join` the `queue_line` thread to wait until it is finished before continuing.

Comment: the `worker_thread` which contain `queue_line` is joined in the `finally` block

Comment: This is too late to avoid that the "In ..." messages appear between the others.

Comment: `In Try` should be before `start` and `In Finally` should be after `join`. Also you should join `print_thread` as well. Note that `join` is to wait until it is finished.

Comment: i think i understand what you guys mean @MichaelButscher and @ken, though i believe you shouldn't join the `print_thread` because that's a `daemon` thread so it shouldn't be join

Comment: My mistake, you do not need `print_thread.join()`. You are doing `print_queue.join()` instead and that is enough.